# Jasmine test a scenario when we are aborting a previous ajax request before making a new request and assigning it back to null after aborting

Tags: jquery, ajax, jasmine

I have a scenario of live search where i need to abort the previous pending ajax request before making a new one. Though I have written the below code and it works fine.

```
App.MyNamespace.xhr = null;
App.MyNamespace.makeAjaxRequest = function() {
if (App.MyNamespace.xhr) {
    App.MyNamespace.xhr.abort();
    App.MyNamespace.xhr = null;
 }
App.MyNamespace.xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.html",
    data: "query",
    });
};
```

I am trying to write a Jasmine test for the same where i need to test both the scenarios where my ajax request calls the abort and also assign the ajax request back to null. My test case below

```
describe('#makeAjaxRequest', function() {
  describe('aborts previous ajax request', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      App.MyNamespace.xhr = jasmine.createSpyObj('App.MyNamespace.xhr', ['abort']);
      App.MyNamespace.makeAjaxRequest();
     });

    it('calls abort on ajax request', function() {
      expect(App.MyNamespace.xhr.abort).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('assigns ajax request to null', function() {
      expect(App.MyNamespace.xhr).toBeNull();
    });
   });
});
```

Now, In the above test case the second it statement i.e. 'assigns ajax request to null' passes but the first it statement i.e. 'calls abort on ajax request' fails with the following error

Failure/Error: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'App.MyNamespace.xhr.abort')

My assumption is jasmine is just checking for the last statement where we are assigning it to null when we call the myAjaxRequest function. Though, the first it statement i.e. 'calls abort on ajax request' passes if I don't assign the App.MyNamespace.xhr request back to null in the actual function.

How do we test this scenario where i can test both the it statements i.e. it should call abort on ajax request as well as assign the ajax request back to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to assign App.MyNamespace.xhr to a variable before calling the App.MyNamespace.makeAjaxRequest() function.

```
describe('#makeAjaxRequest', function() {
  describe('aborts previous ajax request', function() {
    var xhr;

    beforeEach(function() {
      App.MyNamespace.xhr = jasmine.createSpyObj('App.MyNamespace.xhr', ['abort']);
      xhr = App.ModalSearch.xhr;
      App.MyNamespace.makeAjaxRequest();
    });

    it('calls abort on ajax request', function() {
      expect(xhr.abort).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('assigns ajax request to null', function() {
      expect(App.MyNamespace.xhr).toBeNull();
    });
  });
});
```